# jQuery $.each() multidimensional JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

What did I manage do do wrong here? I can't see it, through the first $.each it works, get to the second it stops..

```
var testJSON = {"cluster":[{"node":[{"name":"one", "number":'100', "error":"none"},{"name":"two", "number":'200', "error":"none"},{"name":"three", "number":'300', "error":"found"},{"name":"four", "number":'400', "error":"none"}]}]}

if (testJSON.cluster.length != 0)
{
    $.each(testJSON.cluster, function(i, clstr)
    {
        $('.clusters').append('<ul class="nodes">');
        $.each(clstr.node, function(i, ndes)
        {
            $.find('ul').append('<li>'+ndes.name+'</li>');
        });
        $('.clusters').append('</ul>');
    });
}
```

Comment: Stops? We'll need a bit more than that. Did you receive any uncaught exceptions?

Comment: does the outer each work in the first place? `append()` is adding a DOM node, not text - `append ("</ul>")` seems out of place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
if (testJSON.cluster.length != 0) {
    $.each(testJSON.cluster, function(i, clstr) {
        $('.clusters').append('<ul class="nodes"></ul>');
        $.each(clstr.node, function(i, ndes) {
            $('.clusters ul.nodes').append('<li>' + ndes.name + '</li>');
        });;
    });
}
```

When you append an element, you don't have to later append the closing tag. Also, `find` cannot be called directly from the jQuery object. You need a selector.

Answer (score 2):

What is `$.find`, you are getting an exception in the inner loop and then it stops.

```
$.find('ul').append('<li>'+ndes.name+'</li>');
```

Are you looking for the `ul` which you added in the outer loop? If yes, then use

```
$('.clusters ul').append('<li>'+ndes.name+'</li>')
```